# Django doesnt put uploaded files to the MEDIA_PATH

Tags: python, django

So, I have these settings

```
MEDIA_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and I go to the administration panel and upload a file from it. The module I upload the file to has this:

```
file_upload = models.FileField()
```

However, files instead of going to `project_root/media/` go to just `project_root/`

Why?

Also, when I look up the model and do `model.file_upload.url` it returns an url with `/media/` upfront, so that works.

I also have `DEBUG = True`, I heard that does something to media tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting is [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT) not `MEDIA_PATH`.